# Respond with JSON data from HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a hosting site that allows you to host HTML files with accompanying JavaScript files (using the <scripts> tag). I want to be able to make a POST/GET request to this site and have it return JSON data, as a REST API would.

For example:
If I send a GET request to `myFakeApiSite.com/getObject` I want it to respond with `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}` instead of responding with the contents of the HTML file.

Since this hosting site only allows you to host static HTML/JavaScript pages, you can't use libraries such as Express.js

Comment: HTML/JS is front-end tools and can't set response headers. Change hosting provider

Comment: You just said the web hoster can host javascript files, so why would it be impossible to use express.js ? 
You cannot use <script> tags that include external files ?

And btw you should find a host that support php or other server-side language

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That is not the right way**, but if you like you can make a fetch request again your site. if your site allows cors from other domains then you will get the dom. then you can use regex to catch the jsonstring. with `JSON.parse(string)` you will have the data.

```
fetch('https://www.test-cors.org/')
    .then(function (response) {
        switch (response.status) {
            // status "OK"
            case 200:
                return response.text();
            // status "Not Found"
            case 404:
                throw response;
        }
    })
    .then(function (template) {
        console.log(template);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        // "Not Found"
        console.log(response.statusText);
    });
```